# How to adjust overscan with new Intel Graphics Command Center?

Tags: intel-graphics, intel-core-i5, optimus

I was able to adjust the overscan with the old **Intel Control Panel**, but now I can't since there is no option for this in the new **Intel Graphics Command Center**.

Comment: Do you use an TV as monitor? Because otherwise AFAIK overscan is nowadays no longer necessary.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I do, it's a **Samsung SyncMaster 932MW** from around 2008

Comment: The [FAQ](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000032768/graphics-drivers.html) says that Intel Graphics Command Center can co-exist with the Intel HD Graphics Control Panel. So why not use the old software (unless you have uninstalled it)?

Comment: @harrymc I didn't uninstall it but updated the drivers to **UHC** and now I can't find it in the desktop menu and neither in programs or C:\Program Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was only to download the [legacy Intel drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28289/Legacy-Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-10) and continue using the **Control Panel** instead of the **Command Center**.

Comment: Worked for me. OptiPlex 3070 micro Iris 630 graphics.

Comment: My solution was to upgrade to Windows 11. OptiPlex 3070 micro (Intel 640 integrated graphics).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command center custom scale option. Open the intel command center -> Display -> General, scroll to scale and select custom (as opposed to maintain aspect ratio or whatever). This should then let you set the scale adjustment for the screen by moving the horizontal and vertical sliders.

Comment: This worked for me using Command Center v1.100.4979.0 in 2023, so I think the accepted answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you still looking for solution I got something that worked for me when I was trying to sort this out.

1. Connect your HDMI like usual.
2. On the Intel Graphics Command Center extend your screen and then make your TV the main screen, so that you can see your laptop screen on your TV.
3. Disable screen 1 (laptop) and then you can go to Scaling settings and set to Custom with sliders like the old Intel Graphics Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Intel graphics command center - create a custom resolution that works ***then select Center under aspect ratio***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).